# Update feature for nodejs app running on docker swarm

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-swarm, docker-in-docker

I am running a nodejs app on Docker swarm and I want to implement an update page where the user can upload the update files and the app should run with the updated version, without dealing with the command line. My initial thought was to let users upload exported images to the interface, use a separate updater Docker in Docker application to load the uploaded .tar file to docker daemon as image and run the main app with the new image. But apparently Docker in Docker cannot be run in Docker Swarm. Is there any way I can run it? Or how should I implement this update functionality?

Comment: What exactly should this "update" button do?  From your description it sounds like you're allowing an external user to submit an arbitrary tarball and the application will replace itself with that, but that doesn't seem right.  I'd normally expect code updates to come from a trusted CI system, and a deployment system  would do the work to replace the existing containers with new ones based on the new image.

Comment: @DavidMaze actually it's an app that runs on docker on customer environment. So we obfuscate/build the code, put them inside several docker images, export the images as .tar files, give them to the customer, import them in their machines and run them. But making an update to the app requires exact same steps including stopping the currently running app via terminal etc. We don't want to deal with the terminal after the initial setup.

Comment: Can you use a registry instead of `docker save`?  I can imagine a path where you could download an updated `docker-compose.yml` file with updated `image:` tags and then run `docker-compose up -d`, and that could be automated, but the system that did that would have unlimited administrator privileges over its host.